# Falco installation on Digital Ocean Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, falco

While installing falco on Digital Ocean managed kubernetes. I am getting the following error
`Runtime error: can't open BPF probe '/root/.falco/falco-bpf.o': Errno 2. Exiting. I know this is caused because the ebpf probe was not installed on the cluster nodes.`

But when I try installing without the ebpf probe I get the following error
`Unable to load the driver. Runtime error: error opening device /host/dev/falco0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the falco module is loaded.. Exiting.`

We have to manually install falco and the drivers by sshing into the nodes. After that also we can install only without the ebpf probe, using the kernel module. Has anyone faced with the same issue? Is there any solution to this without doing ssh into the nodes?

Falco version: latest
System info: Worker node Debian 10 Linux kernel 5.10.0
Cloud provider or hardware configuration: 3 vCPU, 6GB Memory, 150 GB Disk
OS: Debian 10
Kernel: Linux 5.10.0
Installation method: from source